# Find summary of values contained in a matrix in python3

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, integer, summary

I would like to know how to do the summary of value contained in a matrix?I currently have this code for input of my matrix:

```
matrix = []
    loop = True
    while loop:
        line = input()
        if not line: 
            loop = False
        values = line.split()
        row = [int(value) for value in values]
        matrix.append(row)
```

For example,the matrix [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] would result 21,the summary of all the values.And im not quite sure on how to do that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in `sum()` function. As your matrix isn't flat, but a list of lists, you need to flatten it for `sum()`:

```py
sum(val for row in matrix for val in row)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
sums = sum(y for x in matrix for y in x)
print sums
```

This runs as:

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> sums = sum(y for x in matrix for y in x)
>>> print sums
21
>>>
```

Or you could use a basic `for` loop:

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
sums = 0
for sub in matrix:
    for value in sub:
        sums+=value

print sums
```

This runs as:

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> sums = 0
>>> for sub in matrix:
...     for value in sub:
...         sums+=value
... 
>>> print sums
21
>>>
```

List comprehension is the same as the double `for` loops, only in one line:

Explanation of the following:

```
sums = sum(y for x in matrix for y in x)
```

Let's start at the beginning:

We use the builtin function `sum()` to calculate all the values in the list:

```
>>> sum([1, 2, 3, 4]) #Should be 10
10
>>>
```

However, `sum()` only works with *flattened* lists:

```
>>> sum([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
>>>
```

Thus, we need to *flatten* it with double `for` loops:

```
sum(y for x in matrix for y in x)
```

The `for x in matrix` is basically taking every value of matrix, essentially `[1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 5, 6]` in this case. The `for y in x` is assigning `y to every value of x`, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. This is our flattened out list. Then we call `sum()`, and everything works like magic!

Answer (score 0):

here is a function that will do that

```
M = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

def matrixSummary( M ):
    rowSums=[]
    for row in M:
        rowSums.append( sum( row ))
    return sum( rowSums )
matrixSummary( M )
// Result: 21 //
```

looks like  CoDEmanX has a nice list comprehension version

Comment: It's a generator expression if I'm not mistaken.